# Python, getting a centered average with a catch

Tags: list, python-3.x, average

So, my assignment is to get the centered average of a list, much like a few of the other posts on here like this one (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/108404/how-to-get-a-centered-mean-excluding-max-and-min-value-of-a-list-in-python) and a few others. However, my professor has told us we are not allowed to use min, max, or sort to solve this. So what I have right now is this, it is still a work in progress:

```
def centered_average(nums):
high=0
low=0
a=0
b=0
for i in range(len(nums)):
    if nums[i]>a:
        a=nums[i]
        high=a
for i in range(len(nums)):
    if nums[i]<b:
        b=nums[i]
        low=b     
total=sum(nums)
average=(total-high-low)/(len(nums)-2)
print(average)
```

My problem is that I can't get low to be recognized as the lowest number in the list. For example, if I input [1,2,3,4,5] as the list, my function should return 5 as the high, 1 as the low, and 3 as the centered average since 2+3+4 is 9/3=3. However, what I have right there returns the low as 0. I think it is because of the (lens(nums) since it would think the first number is a 0. I'm not sure how I should fix this.

**Note**: I am still a beginner at this stuff so I know what I have might not be the best or that  the error could be simple to fix, but I am still in the process of learning so any help and advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: `if nums[i] < b` , but b is initialized to zero. So if all are positive numbers, you may not get the right number. One option is to initialize b to `nums[0]`. Do the same for a. `a, b = nums[0], nums[0]`

Comment: Is there a reason it returns the high correctly as 5 when i have it setup as if nums[i]>a?

Comment: Because `1>0(the initialized a)` , `2>1`, `3>2`, `4>3`, `5>4` . However, in the minimum case, nothing is less than 0.

Comment: I tried that but it's not working. Unless I put it in wrong. I got rid of the `a=0` and the `b=0` and put the `a,b=nums[0],nums[0]`  did i do it wrong?

Comment: so `a` and `b` are actually `high` and `low`. You can remove `high` and `low`. Whats happening is, since `nums[0]` is low, the `nums[i] < b` never gets executed so `low=b` never happens. hence `low=0`. You could just use `a` and `b` as `high` and `low`. A better option is to use the answer provided by Amadan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your starting the running minimum (and running maximum) as `0`.

Start the running minimum as `float("inf")` (as everything is guaranteed to be less than that). Start the running maximum as `float("-inf")` (as everything is guaranteed to be greater than that).

Or, start both as the first element of the list (which is either a true minimum/maximum, or there's another element that is lower/higher than it).

Comment: So if i did something like`b=nums[1]` it would work? If i had a list like [3,4,2,1,5,5] would it start as a 3 but then as it ran through the list it would then go to 2 and finally to 1 since it is the smallest?

Comment: Actually, that just solved it. Thank you for the help. I didn't think of actually setting it to a list variable.